# SQL - ignore foreign characters

Tags: sql

I want my query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE STREET = 'Onska'
```

to return records also `where STREET = 'Ońską'`

So database value contains some special, foreign characters. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Use collation that has 'Ońską' equal to 'Onska'.

Comment: Yes but it would work only for this one word. I need it to work every time for any foreign characters.

Comment: It should work for more or less any foreign character, depending on the collation used.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different sets of collations, and different collation names.)